# Keep an HTML element from spanning multiple pages when printed

Tags: html, css, printing, page-break

I have the following HTML that I would like to keep from being broken up when spanning multiple pages. The problem is that if I use page-break-before or after, it will put each element on it's own page. The other problem I'm having is that if I set `display: block` on either the `cell` CSS class or the `wrap` class, the DIV or LI still gets broken up. I have a print media CSS file and a CSS file for the screen as well. I want to keep the `<li class="cell">` element and its contents from being broken up.

```
        <div class="pad">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; margin: 10px 0">

            Work Orders for Jan 05, 2011
        </h1>
        <p class="printHidden">
            <a href="/orders/print-all/date/2011-01-05">Print All Work Orders</a>
        </p>
        <ul class="workorders">                    
            <li class="cell">
                <div class="wrap" id="146">

                    <div class="scheduled">
                        <p>
                            <strong>Work Order:</strong> <a href="/orders/view/work-order/146">158801</a>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Client:</strong> Client Name
                        </p><br>

                        <b>Resources</b>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/resources/view/resource-id/5" id="Person-5">Mikell McLaindon</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/resources/view/resource-id/9" id="Person-9">Jose Copper</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="unschedule printHidden">
                        <h1 style="text-align: center; margin: 10px 0 10px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">
                            Unschedule Resource for 15880-PW
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            {... removed for brevity ...}
```

Comment: Could you post the mark-up that's seen by the browser (`view source` in browser) rather than the php/pre-processor version?

Comment: Your PHP/Perl/whatever code is irrelevant; you should show us the same HTML as the browser sees _(hint: View Source)_.

Comment: @Elijah Saounkine: Standard US 8.5"x11" page size.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**EDIT: PROPER SOLUTION**

See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_print_pagebi.asp
So if you add the following to your CSS it should fix your problem:

```
@media print
{
    div.pad { page-break-inside:avoid; }
}
```

All the major desktop browsers now support this.

However, there is also `page-break-after:avoid` and `page-break-before:avoid` which you can add to **every element within the `.pad` class** in order to produce the same result in some older versions of browsers.

```
@media print
{
    div.pad * { 
        page-break-after:avoid;
        page-break-before:avoid;
    }
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_print_pagebb.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_print_pageba.asp

**OLD ANSWER:**

It sounds like you're trying to fit something on a page that doesn't fit on a page.  I would try adding a stylesheet with `media="print"`...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" charset="utf-8" />
```

...that reduces the font size, padding, etc. of all of these elements so that you CAN put a page break before this section and have it fit on the page.

Comment: I am not talking about just one element, it is a series of 'boxes' if you will and sometimes a box happens to be broken up by a page break. I want to keep the <li class="cell"> and its contents from being broken up.

Comment: Ah, of course.  I will replace my answer with a proper solution should I find one.

Comment: ...and it looks like I found one

Comment: +1 for the answer, for *improving* your answer, and *keeping the old one* =)

Comment: @mVChr The link in your proper solution gives me a 404. You wouldn't happen to know the new link would you?

Comment: The new links are:
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp